# Thread Implementation in Spring AMQP while consumption of Message

Tags: java, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have an application which consumes a message from RabbitMQ using Spring AMQP.
I have to implement Threads in consumer to handle the request. If my threads pool are available , i am consuming the message using threads i will process the message.

> I have a question where what happens when all the threads are busy. I
>   dont have a threads to process it. Will the message be consumed from
>   RabbitMQ ? Will it wait till my thread pool becomes available. How do
>   handle this using spring amqp?

**Is there any thread logic to be implemented from Spring AMQP side as well**?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

You should not add your own threading in your listener, it will cause messages to be ack'd early and potentially lost. Instead, use the container's `concurrentConsumers` property to determine how many threads to use.

I suggest you read about all the [configuration options](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#containerAttributes) before asking questions like this here.